# Call Jquery Autocomplete ajax function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, autocomplete

I have a Jquery autocomplete ajax function whose source is calculated from code behind. however I am getting the source in javascript using client script manager but my function doesn't execute.

Apart from that I am trying to call that ajax function from code behind through

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()
```

But again my function doesn't execute.
My function is:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Text1" type="text"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id="Text2" type="text" /><br />
        <br />
        <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mydataformat = [{ label: "....", value: "....", icon: "....." }, 
                        { label: "....", value: ".....", icon: "....." }];

    $(function() {
    $("#Text1").autocomplete({                      
    minLength: 0,                      
    source: JSVar,                      
    focus: function (event, ui) 
    {
    $("#Text1").val(ui.item.label);                          
    return false;                      
    }})                     
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {                         
    return $("<li></li>") 
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)                             
    .append("<a><img src='" + item.icon + "' width='32' height='32' />  " + item.label + "</a>")                             
    .appendTo(ul);                     
        }; 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Is your function in a jquery onready handler like `$(function(){//is your code here?});`

Comment: yes it is. but unfortunately i am not able to add my data calculated from database query to the source of this jquery function.

Comment: if you put `source: mydataformat,` (with some valid values of course) it works when you type something from that list in the text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the source when your data has been loaded like mentioned [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source):

```
$("#Text1").autocomplete( "option", "source", ["your", "loaded", "data"] );
```

...or better initialize your autocomplete when your calculated data is ready, not earlier.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the data to be entered here is dynamic and has a format with keywords label, value and icon.

Comment: how do i do that? initialize autocomplete when data is ready?

Comment: When is your data ready? When has your js var be filled? There must be a place where you fill/set `JSVar`. And **after** that you have to set your autocomplete code.

Comment: In code-behind page, i accessed the required data from database in `page_load` method, after which i am trying to either call the entire javascript function from code-behind or pass `JSVar` to client-side. In either cases, i am not able to call autocomplete function.

Comment: I edited my question for the entire form. Please check. And yeah it consists of simple html textbox and button

Comment: But where is your `JSVar` defined? I don't get it.

Comment: In the code-behind. i appended all the database result into JSVar and then passed it to client-side using `ClientScriptManager`. I am getting correct result when i check through `alert(JSVar)` but it does not apply to autocomplete

Comment: Thats the important point - please post that code where you assign JSVar!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Custom Data sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) on the jQueryUI site, it seems to cover everything you want. It uses label, value, icon etc.

The only remaining piece is to wait until after your data has loaded before you initialise it.

Comment: i hv used the same. And for waiting, i am already registering the entire javascript function after my database query in code-behind. but it doesn't seem to execute well. Any suggestions?